# sql select query on a table is not finishing

Tags: mysql, blocking

I'm experiencing this weird problem reading data from a table called nodes. Any select query is taking forever to execute. I don't even know if its going to return eventually but it doesn't seem like that. It used to return quickly before. Nothing has changed as far as I know. No new records are inserted and none are deleted too. Couple of queries that I tried.

```
select count(1) from  nodes;

select node_id, type from nodes where node_id='abc';
```

node_id is a primary key in nodes table if that helps. The previous day all of select queries used to return in no time like in 0.01ms etc.

My guess is that somehow a lock is placed on the table preventing my queries from proceeding.
I appreciate if someone can let me know or give a pointer to how to find locks on a particular table in MYSQL 5.0.90-log FreeBSD.

What could be other possibilities?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Can you run "SHOW PROCESSLIST" and see what's going on in the background? Also, try to put EXPLAIN in front of your SELECT statements to see if anything weird is going on. And... check for corrupt databases.

Comment: explain didn't help, well it blocked too. "show processlist" says the state of all select queries on nodes is "Locked". The queries that I cancelled are not really cancelled. How should I proceed now?

Comment: Please see this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-locking.html Table locking can happen for many reasons. While restarting the server might fix for now, it's always good to know what happened in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I escalated this problem to a senior staff in our group. He figured that when mysqld tried to log, file system has become full. This is solved by stopping mysqld and creating a symbolic link to a file on a different file system that has lots of free space. started mysqld and all select queries are running without blocking.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at processes on you server, maybe you have to kill someone of them to free the table.

Here is an interesting link about that:
http://mysqlpreacher.com/wordpress/2009/07/mysql-processlist-showkill-processes/

Comment: thanks,you solve my problem,i have 2 applications on local sever connect to my sql server when I disconnect both them  work correctly and again run my applications.

Answer (score 1):

First try to restart the sql service if that doesn't help, rebuild the indexes .

Answer (score 0):

May be indexes got curropted. Try rebuilding all indexes.

Comment: Are you able to resolve it? If yes please share it may help someone.